# My Div is causing horizontal scroll bars when window is resized

Tags: horizontal-scrolling

Has anybody got a solution to the problem of my div going out of the body container when the window is resized and therefore causing scroll bars?

Here is the code: http://www.cssdesk.com/NTHML (JSFiddle is messing up)

Would appreciate any help and an explanation if possible, thank you very much!